# How to show all columns in Angular UI grid except X?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I understand how to hide a column in Angular UI-grid:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {      
  columnDefs: [
    { name: 'id', visible : false },
  ],
};
```

But if I only define which columns I want *hidden*, the grid automatically assumes that I also define which columns I want to have *visible*, however this is not the case so this results in an empty grid.

Is it possible to configure the grid to show '**all columns except those configured to be hidden**'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible as stated in [GridOptions api](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions#properties_excludeproperties).

You just need to add `excludeProperties` instead of `columnDefs` and assign it an array of strings where every string is a property to hide in your grid.

In your example you should just write:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {      
  excludeProperties: ['id'],
};
```

Comment: Don't know how I missed that one. Thanks a lot!